# pandas series to multi-column html

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas series (slice of larger DF corresponding to a single record) that I would like to display as html. While i can convert the Series to a DataFrame and use the `.to_html()` function this will result in a two-column html output. To save space/give a better aspect ratio I would like to return a four- or six-column HTML table where the series has been wrapped into two or three sets of index-value columns, like so.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series( [12,34,56,78,54,77], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f'])
#pd.DataFrame(s).to_html()
#will yield 2 column hmtl-ed output 
# I would like a format like this:
a 12  d 78
b 34  e 54
c 56  f 77
```

This is what I have currently:

```
x = s.reshape((3,2))
y = s.index.reshape((3,2))
new = [ ]
for i in range(len(x)):
    new.append(y[i])
    new.append(x[i])
 z = pd.DataFrame(new)
 z.T.to_html(header=False, index=False)
```

Is there a better way that I might have missed?

thanks
zach cp

Comment: do you need it to be html or can it be also string?

Comment: the goal is to output to html. since there is already a to_html function for the DataFrame I think using that would be simplest. but if you have another solution - I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler. The ordering is slightly different (read across rows, not down columns), but I'm not sure if that will matter to you.

```
In [17]: DataFrame(np.array([s.index.values, s.values]).T.reshape(3, 4))
Out[17]: 
   0   1  2   3
0  a  12  b  34
1  c  56  d  78
2  e  54  f  77
```

As in your example, you'll need to omit the "header" and the index from the HTML.

Comment: Hi Dan,while the format is a little different than I would like, you method is much nicer. I'm going to wait a few more minuted to see if anyone else chimes in before accepting this.